# I don't know what I am doing wrong setting the cookie?

Tags: node.js, cookies

So I am using nodejs and mongodb and trying to set a cookie on one of the pages.

In the app.js file, it is pretty standard using this

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , dbUserModel = require('./models/user')
  , db = require('./db')
  , pass = require('./config/passport')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , routes = require('./routes/index')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , path = require('path')
  , http = require('http')
  , connect = require('connect')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , mongoConnect = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test5');

// all environments

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');


    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
  ///app.use(express.cookieSession());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    
});
  app.get('/', routes.index)
  app.get('/register', user.register);
  app.post('/register', user.registerPost);
  app.get('/registerError', user.registerError);
  app.get('/registerThanks', user.registerThanks);
  app.get('/login', user.login);
  app.post('/login', user.loginPost);
  app.get('/loginError', user.loginError);
  app.get('/userProfile', user.userProfile);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
  console.log('Users: ' + db.collections.users);
});
```

Then I am calling my route file.

This is my code:

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', {user: req.user, title: 'Weblio'});
};

exports.loginPost = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('loginError'); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.redirect('userProfile');
        });
  })(req, res, next);
};

exports.loginError = function (req, res) {
    res.render('loginError', {title: 'Weblio'});
};

exports.userProfile = function(req, res) {      
    res.render('userProfile', {user: req.user, title: 'Weblio'});
    res.cookie('name', 'test', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true }); 

};
```

When I go to the userProfile page and in the console I type in document.cookie it shows an empty string as the result.

I also tried moving the res.cookie into the login post and it was not working...

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify cookies after sending the response headers to the client, regardless of the programming language you're using. When calling `res.render()` it sends the headers along with the actual view.

HTTP cookies are are part of the headers being sent to the client.

Try calling `res.cookie()` before your `res.render()` that sends the response to the client.

Also, when calling `app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));` you are creating a 'signed' cookie, by giving the 'secret' parameter.
Thus, when changing the cookie, you must tell express that you are handling a signed cookie like this :
`res.cookie('name', 'test', {maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true, signed: true});`

You can read more about cookies here : http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/

Comment: The cookie still appears to leave an empty string, when I changed its position to before render.

Comment: It should work - I'm guessing you have something else in the way bothering you. Edit your question to remove the unnevessary code with the other routes, and show me the app.js file instead...

Comment: Should I be running app.use(express.cookieSession()); right after the cookieParser, I have it commented out in the code above. Also, if I still do document.cookie in console. The cookie is an empty string still.

Comment: I don't think `cookieSession()` should be a problem although im not 100% sure about that. Anyway, after setting the cookie before the render call and telling the cookie that it's signed it should be working. I have done it quite a few times. The only thing i can think of now is that the `passport` module you're using is interfering with the cookie, maybe by setting response headers before you are... I would try to remove the lines that have `app.use(passport....)` just to check if it solves the problem.